# Javascript: Expand / Collapse Multiple DIV's with simple code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have several DIVs on my page that I would like to be able to expand / collapse. I'm using the code below to do so, but it only applies to an entire class.. Can I apply it to whatever is being clicked? (for example, self.slideToggle();)

```
// Activate Toggle for Showing / Hiding More Price Tables
        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    return false;
    });

});
```

EDIT: Here is an example of markup:

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Video & Music</a>
    <div class="slidingDiv">CONTENT HERE</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work.

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
      $(this).next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
      return false;
});
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ABrunkhorst/vFnqp/1/

Comment: Edited to show markup. That code you mentioned made the DIVs disappear forever haha

Answer (score 1):

use `$(this)` inside the click event.

or if you click on something in the div then something like the parent keyword.

so `$(this).parent(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();`

**edit**

you could i think also use this, based on your edit;

```
$(this).next('.slidingDiv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `$(this)` inside the function call will reference the object in scope, in this case the one being clicked.

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
   $(this).next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
   return false;
});
```

Instead of `next()` you may consider:

- **`children()`** - *to only select the first level of children*
- **`contents()`** - *if you're trying to get all descendents (children + children of children) of the element being clicked*
- **`siblings()`** - *to get all elements that are on the same level in the hierarchy tree*
- **`prev()`** - *to get the previous sibling*
- **`next()`** - *to get the first sibling*
- **`prevAll()`** - *to get all the previous siblings*
- **`nextAll()`** - *to get all the next siblings*
- **`parents()`** - *to get the anscestors (wrappers) of the clicked element*

Comment: thanks for reply, but this didn't work... the DIVs didn't expand or collapse at all

Comment: Zakman411: your markup was limited and the indentation makes it look like the div is nested, you should clean up your markup.  I've revised the answer above, but you should list the complete mark-up

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of JQUERY UI Accordion using which we can efficiently toggle.
We must add the following JQuery links

```
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>  $(function() {   
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion(); 
    });  
   </script> 
   <div id="accordion"> 
   <h3>Section 1</h3>
   <div>   
   <p>This is division 1  
   </p></div>  
   <h3>Section 2</h3>
   <div>
   <p>This is division2</p></div>
```

For more details Refer this http://jqueryui.com/accordion/